How to auto increment value in update SQL statement
I am having SQL data in my Employee table like below. EmpId is primary key and TName is having empty string with no value

| EmpId    | TName    |  GrId 
| -------- | -------- | ---------  
| 1        |          |  AA        
-----------------------------------
| 2        |          |  AA        
-----------------------------------
| 3        |          |  BB       
-----------------------------------
| 4        |          |  BB        
-----------------------------------
| 5        |          |  BB        
-----------------------------------


I want to auto increment the TName value based on the grouping of this column "GrId"
For EmpId = 1 and 2 we are having same GrId so we can start incremented with +1 and for EmpId=3,4,5
we are having another GrId so again start incrementing from beginning (zero) with +1
I cannot use Identity constraint on my TName column
I have tried like this but throwing error
Update T
Set T.TName = '('+ (select CAST(Count(*) + 1 AS Nvarchar(max)) from Employee) + ')' 
from Employee T
Where 1=1 
group by T.GrId

My expected output:
| EmpId    | TName    |  GrId 
| -------- | -------- | ---------  
| 1        |   (1)    |  AA        
-----------------------------------
| 2        |   (2)   |  AA        
-----------------------------------
| 3        |   (1)   |  BB       
-----------------------------------
| 4        |   (2)   |  BB       
-----------------------------------
| 5        |   (3)   |  BB       
-----------------------------------



Look into Row_Number   PARTITION BY GrID

Have a look at this answer1

SELECT EmpId, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GrID  ORDER BY EmpID) TName, 
    GrId
FROM Employee

Fiddle



EmpId
TName
GrId




1
1
AA


2
2
AA


3
1
BB


4
2
BB


5
3
BB




OP: to use this in an UPDATE place it inside a CTE and update the CTE, for example WITH cte AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() ... AS NewTName FROM ... ) UPDATE cte SET TName = NewTName;
